# Logback could not find external property file resource

Tags: jndi, logback

I am using logback version 1.0.13. 
To read external property resource from logback, i used a JNDI entry (defined in Tomcat Context) :

```
...
<insertFromJNDI env-entry-name="java:comp/env/app.config.path" as="app.config.path" /> 
<property resource="${app.config.path}" />
....
```

Problem : logback not find my JNDI resource : ${app.config.path}=file:///D:/temp/application.properties

```
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.PropertyAction - Could not find resource [file:///D:/temp/application.properties]
```

not work with other URLs like :  `file://D:/, file:/D:/, file:////D:/,...`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

As Bidit Kumar pointed out, file approach also works. In my case I had a similar problem and my solution is as below (I applied solution 2)

Solution:

1. `<property
       file="C:\myproject\src\main\resources\com\mycompany\app.properties"/>`
2. `<property resource="\com\mycompany\app.properties"/>`

Comment: I think he talks about the case when the properties file is outside the project. Not within src/main/resources folder. I have a case where the application.properties is within tomcat_dir/conf. Totally confused how to access the file.

Answer (score 2):

### The Set-up:

*Language:* Java

*Application:* Spring Boot App

*Project:* Maven

*Logging:* Logback

*Container:* (Jetty for development | Tomcat for production)

---

### The Situation:

In our project we have logback.xml at the root of resources. This file needs to access specific application properties. In in the example below the property that we need to access is `logging.home.dir` which will be stored as `LOGGER_HOME`.

Example: logback.xml

```
<configuration> 
  <property name="LOGGER_HOME" value="${logging.home.dir}" />

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOGGER_HOME}/application.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- other setting --> 
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
      <!-- other setting --> 
    </encoder>
  </appender>
</configuration>
```

---

### The Problem:

Normally for development one can use the default application property file `application.properties` to hold all the required properties but for production this file is externalized.

***Development***

```
application.properties
logging.home.dir=temp/logs/
```

- For development as long as the `application.proerties` file is available on the classpath it can be referenced within logback.xml using `<property resource="application.properties" />`

***Production***

```
Location: /opt/production/tc8-java8/my_wonderfull_app/application-prod.properties
application-prod.properties
logging.home.dir=application/logs/
```

- This file is located externally to the app . Unfortunately as this file doesn’t sit on the classpath we cannot load this file as we did in development.

---

### The Solution:

To allow logback to use the external property file you will need to do the following:

**Step 1:**  When starting the application, you will need to add a VM option indicating where to load the external property file:
`-Dmy.wonderful.app.external.properties.file=/opt/production/tc8-java8/my_wonderfull_app/application-prod.properties`

**Step 2:** In the logback file you can now use 
`<property file="${my.wonderful.app.external.properties.file}" /> <!-- note this MUST match the VM option name -->`

`<property name="LOGGER_HOME" value="${logging.home.dir}" /> <!-- property key from the file -->`

---

### Short Answer:

*Application VM option*

-D`my.wonderful.app.external.properties.file`=/opt/production/tc8-java8/my_wonderfull_app/application-prod.properties

*Logback.xml*

< property file="${`my.wonderful.app.external.properties.file`}" />

---

> *Note 1:* For Intellij adding a VM Option can be done via Run/Debug Configuration > Spring Boot > [Configuration > Environment > ‘VM options:’]
>
> *Note 2:* For Tomcat adding a VM Option can be done in /bin/setenv.sh
>   CATALINA_OPTS=-Dmy.wonderful.app.external.properties.file=/opt/production/tc8-java8/my_wonderfull_app/application-prod.properties

Answer (score 0):

Try using file="${app.config.path}" instead of resource="${app.config.path}"

and ${app.config.path}= D:/...

Check logback documentation for more details: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

Rodrigo

This is my config.properties file:

```
logging.path = ./
logging.file = sync.log
logging.maxHistory = 5
logging.app.level = INFO
logging.libs.level = DEBUG
```

And my logback.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <property file="config.properties" />

    <!-- Console -->
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
             <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{60} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- File -->
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${logging.path}${logging.file}</file>
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <fileNamePattern>${logging.path}${logging.file}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}</fileNamePattern>
                <maxHistory>${logging.maxHistory}</maxHistory>
            </rollingPolicy>
           <encoder>
               <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{160} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
           </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.amazon" level="${logging.libs.level}"/>
    <logger name="com.amazonaws" level="${logging.libs.level}"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.http" level="${logging.libs.level}"/>
    <logger name="com.zaxxer.hikari" level="${logging.libs.level}"/>
    <logger name="org.flywaydb" level="${logging.libs.level}"/>

    <root level="${logging.app.level}">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

SpringApplication loads properties from application.properties files in the following locations and adds them to the Spring Environment:

1. A /config subdirectory of the current directory
2. The current directory
3. A classpath /config package
4. The classpath root

If you do not like application.properties(cases where you want it to be different for dev, stage, production environment ) as the configuration file name, you can switch to another file name by specifying a spring.config.name environment property. You can also refer to an explicit location by using the spring.config.location environment property

You can try the following (Eclipse),

Set Environment variables SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION and SPRING_CONFIG_NAME with appropriate values in run configuration.

[image]

In logback.xml, add the below property

```
<property
        file="${SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION}${SPRING_CONFIG_NAME}.properties" />
```

Now you can access the property(say variablename.xyz) present in your properties file as below,

```
<property name="MY_PROPERTY" value="${variablename.xyz}" />
```